# Filter specific key(s) in array of objects that contain search term in any specified key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering, javascript-objects

What woule be the best/fastest way to filter array of objects by searcing for specific term in specific key value pair(s)?

Let's say we have an array of objects, array of desired keys and search term string.

The array of objects:

```
const posts = [
  {
     postId: 1,
     title: "Hello my friends", 
     text: "To all my friends",
     description: "Random text"
  },
  {
     postId: 2,
     title: "To all my friends", 
     text: "Hello my friends",
     description: "Hello text"
  },
  {
     postId: 3,
     title: "My friends", 
     text: "To all my friends",
     description: "Random Hello",
  },
  {
     postId: 4,
     title: "Hello my friends", 
     text: "To all my friends Hello",
     description: "again"
  }
];
```

Array of keys:

```
const keys = ['title', 'text'];
```

Search term:

```
const searchTerm: 'Hello';
```

Output should be:

```
const filteredArray = [
   {
     postId: 1,
     title: "Hello my friends", 
     text: "To all my friends",
     description: "Random text"
   },
   {
     postId: 2,
     title: "To all my friends", 
     text: "Hello my friends",
     description: "Hello text"
   },
   {
     postId: 4,
     title: "Hello my friends", 
     text: "To all my friends Hello",
     description: "again"
   }
];
```

Only the third object should not be in filtered array in this example.

I tried this approach: https://jsfiddle.net/pnc75tzg/

I have duplicates inside array. I guess I could check if that object already exists in array before push.

But overall I don't think this would be a good approach.
Any idea on what would be a good approach to filter this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) combined with [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) here. Since only 1 of the keys satisfying the condition is enough `some` can be used. If all the keys should have the search string use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) instead of `some`.

`some` returns true if at least 1 element in the `keys` array satisfies the condition i.e the string 'Hello' is included in the corresponding value of the key.
On the other hand `every` returns true only if all the elements satisfy the condition

```js
const posts = [  {     postId: 1,     title: "Hello my friends",      text: "To all my friends",     description: "Random text"  },  {     postId: 2,     title: "To all my friends",      text: "Hello my friends",     description: "Hello text"  },  {     postId: 3,title: "My friends",      text: "To all my friends",     description: "Random Hello",  },  {     postId: 4,     title: "Hello my friends",      text: "To all my friends Hello",     description: "again"  }];

const keys = ['title', 'text'];
const searchTerm = 'Hello';

const filteredPosts = posts.filter((post) => keys.some((key) => post[key].includes(searchTerm)))

console.log(filteredPosts)
```

if all the keys need to satisfy

```js
const posts = [  {     postId: 1,     title: "Hello my friends",      text: "To all my friends",     description: "Random text"  },  {     postId: 2,     title: "To all my friends",      text: "Hello my friends",     description: "Hello text"  },  {     postId: 3,title: "My friends",      text: "To all my friends",     description: "Random Hello",  },  {     postId: 4,     title: "Hello my friends",      text: "To all my friends Hello",     description: "again"  }];

const keys = ['title', 'text'];
const searchTerm = 'Hello';

const filteredPosts = posts.filter((post) => keys.every((key) => post[key].includes(searchTerm)))

console.log(filteredPosts)
```